# Getting Leiningen to download dependencies outside of a project

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm learning Clojure, but I'm not really building whole projects for each little code snippet, I just drop them into a REPL. Occasionally code snippets I'm exploring require a dependency (usually something that is/was in clojure.contrib).

The only way I know how to get those dependencies onto my computer is to have an empty leiningen project, add the dependency to project.clj and run `lein deps`.

Is there any way I can download libraries *globally, outside of a project*? If it's that I really *really* don't want to, why?

Comment: 1) download library jar 2) `java -cp clojure.jar:some-lib-clj.jar clojure.main` 3) What's so bad about having a scratch Leiningen project?

Comment: it's not exactly what you want I think but maybe this will make it easier, https://github.com/mtyaka/lein-oneoff

Comment: Seems to me that this is _exactly_ what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

I have a small project that I use for testing code snippets and answering SO questions, and am also constantly adding dependencies. The project.clj for this project includes [Pomegranate](https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate) as a dependency which then makes dynamically loading other dependencies as easy as:

```
(use '[cemerick.pomegranate :only (add-dependencies)])
(add-dependencies :coordinates '[[my-dependency "1.2.3"]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Give [lein-try](https://github.com/rkneufeld/lein-try) a go. It's a leiningen plugin I wrote that lets you say something like `lein try [my-dependency 1.0.0]` or even `lein try my-dependency` at the command line and drop into a REPL with the dependency available.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using lein-exec as your way of running one-off scripts, you can now use a little snippet at the top of the script.  Add:

```
(use '[leiningen.exec :only (deps)])
(deps '[[clj-time "0.8.0"]])
```

to the top of your clj.  Now running `lein exec [example.clj]` will automatically pull down the requirement.

If you are new to lein exec, just add `{:user {:plugins [[lein-exec "0.3.4"]]}}` to your `~/.lein/profiles.clj` and you can begin running lein exec on your clj files.  It is a great and quick way to run code without a project.